# Rest Assured - Extract a single value from a list of multiple records with GPath

Tags: java, groovy, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a list of records:

```
{
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "Result": [
    {
      "Id": 15015600,
      "Amount": 97.41,
      "CreatedDate": "10/17/2018",
    },
    {
      "Id": 15015602,
      "Amount": 682.11,
      "CreatedDate": "10/17/2018",
    },
   and so on...
```

I'm trying to craft a statement to return the "Id" value when I know the Amount and CreatedDate.

```
int Id = given()
            .when()
                .get(/EndPoint))
            .then()
                .body("Result.findAll { it.Amount==97.41 }.CreatedDate", hasItems("10/17/2018"));
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to achieve here: are you try to consume JSON or to validate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
int i = response.path("Result.find{it.Amount.toDouble()==293.51 && it.CreatedDate=='10/26/2018'}.Id");
```

I needed to add, "toDouble()" to my query.  it.Amount.toDouble()==293.51, not it.Amount==293.51.   Once the toDouble() was added the query worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you have list of records as a List, not as a json String, you can just call

```
def id = YourResponse.Result.find{it.Amount==97.41 && it.CreatedDate=="10/17/2018"}
```

It will return you first found result that matches your search condition. If you call findAll instead of find with the same closure, you will have list of all matches.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to tell if you have already parsed your JSON, so I included code to do that too. This is plain Groovy, not Rest Assured specific.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def text = '''
{
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "Result": [
    {
      "Id": 15015600,
      "Amount": 97.41,
      "CreatedDate": "10/17/2018",
    },
    {
      "Id": 15015602,
      "Amount": 682.11,
      "CreatedDate": "10/17/2018",
    }
   ]
}'''
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(text)
assert json.Result.find{ it.Amount == 97.41 && it.CreatedDate == '10/17/2018' }.Id == 15015600
```

Comment: I'm really new to groovy and api's in general.  How can I use this to pull the Id value out and store it in a variable?  You say, "def json = new JsonSlurper()..." and so on but what would that actually look like in some java code?